# What is the terminology for "floating links"?

Tags: terminology

Quite often I come across this type of an answer:

```
The answer is in this mechanism. [2 lines of mechanism] Your mistake was [2 lines] 

https://link.to.com/a_research_paper

Also note that another reason is [2 lines]
```

The pattern here is that the user writes an answer, and in the middle of it, leaves a "floating link" - whose connection with either paragraph is unclear and requires some explanation.

It is not clear whether it's supposed to be a "Read more here" link, or a "Source from" link, or a "The full answer is here" link, or any other application the viewer could think of. A better way to write that link would have `[How is this url supposed to help the reader?](url)` (assuming markdown, but you get the point) Without the latter, this hurts user experience.

Far too often, I've found myself calling these "floating links", but I am not sure if this is the correct terminology. What is the correct terminology to refer to such links?

Comment: As an aside: Never use a link that ends with the word 'here'. Users browsing via screen readers tend to tab-navigate by skipping from link to link until they reach what they're looking for. Phrases like "click here" or "Read more here" have no context for the user to evaluate their usefulness. Phrases like "Read more about floating links" are much more useful

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar concept in programming called a "dangling comment" in IntelliJ IDEA IDE.

Such usage of comments considered a bad practice, there is even a code inspection defined in the IDE that only purpose is to indicate such an improper use of comments, it's called:

> Dangling Javadoc comment

And described as:

> Reports dangling Javadoc comments. Javadoc comment are dangling if
>   they don't belong to any class, method or field. For example a Javadoc
>   comment in between method declarations that have their own javadoc
>   comments.

Perhaps, such naming can be applied for the links described in the question as well.

Comment: Yeah, this is a nice parallel comparison between the two fields ^_^